# Convert POST Request to Doctrine Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Coming from a NodeJS environment, this seems like a nobrainer but I somehow did not figured it out.

given the function:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="create_stuff", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function createTouristAttraction($futureEntity): JsonResponse
    {
      ...
     }
```

Let **futureEntity** have the same structure as my PersonEntity.

What is *the* best way of mapping that $futureEntity to a PersonEntity?

I tried to assign it manually, and then run my validations which seems to work, but i think this is cumbersome if a model has more than 30 fields...

Hint: Im on Symfony 4.4

Thank you!

Comment: The Symfony Form component takes care of the mapping and validation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doc: [How to process forms in Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms)

1. You need to install the Form bundle: `composer require symfony/form` (or `composer require form` if you have the Flex bundle installed)
2. Create a new **App\Form\PersonType** class to set the fields of your form and more: [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes)
3. In **App\Controller\PersonController**, when you instanciate the Form, just pass `PersonType::class` as a first parameter, and an new empty Person entity as a second one (the Form bundle will take care of the rest):

---

```
$person = new Person();
$form = $this->createForm(PersonType::class, $person);
```

---

**The whole controller code:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Person;
use App\Form\PersonType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class PersonController extends AbstractController
{

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/person/new", name="person_new")
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $person = new Person(); // <- new empty entity
        $form = $this->createForm(PersonType::class, $person);

        // handle request (check if the form has been submited and is valid)
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 

            $person = $form->getData(); // <- fill the entity with the form data

            // persist entity
            $this->entityManager->persist($person);
            $this->entityManager->flush();

            // (optional) success notification
            $this->addFlash('success', 'New person saved!');

            // (optional) redirect
            return $this->redirectToRoute('person_success');
        }

        return $this->renderForm('person/new.html.twig', [
            'personForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

4. The minimum to display your form in **templates/person/new.html.twig**: just add `{{ form(personForm) }}` where you want.

Comment: That it exactly what i was looking for. Thank you! Why is that not documented properly?

Comment: This SymfonyCasts website is very usefull to get more human-oriented explanations aout symfony ;) For example: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms